# why text-decoration is not working in this situation?

Tags: html, css

Do you know reason that text-decoration is not working on in this case?

```css
#menu {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='menu'>
  <a href='1.html'>Home</a>
  <a href='2.html'>Home</a>
  <a href='3.html'>Home</a>
  <a href='4.html'>Home</a>
</div>
```

By the way, below css code was worked.

```css
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: The reason is because you are assigning the css formatting to the box, not the element itself.

Answer (score 2):

- **text-decoration** is not an inherited property.
- If you really need to apply this to children of **#menu**, you'll need to explicitly `inherit` them.

```css
#menu   { text-decoration: none;    }
#menu a { text-decoration: inherit; }
```

```html
<div id='menu'>
  <a href='1.html'>Home</a>
  <a href='2.html'>Home</a>
  <a href='3.html'>Home</a>
  <a href='4.html'>Home</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will work.

```css
#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='menu'>
  <a href='1.html'>Home</a>
  <a href='2.html'>Home</a>
  <a href='3.html'>Home</a>
  <a href='4.html'>Home</a>
</div>
```

In your version you selected the `#menu` element itself and not it its children.

The CSS-selector `#menu a` will address all `<a>` elements that are descendents (direct or indirect children) of an element with the id `menu`.

In case you only want direct children of `#menu` to be affected you should use `#menu > a` instead.

Comment: Hey, please give me some time to finish my sentence! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The **text-decoration** is not inherited (so the `<a>` element will not inherit it from the `<div>` element), this is why "it is not working" in the first case.

Also, each browser has some default CSS values, and most of the browsers have a default **text-decoration: underline** for `<a>` elements.

As you have already noticed, once you target the correct element (`<a>` and not #menu, which is a `<div>`), it will work!